# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Here there is a error in the fn `print_list()` where the compiler is showing the following error

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token
```

Please help since i am new in this.

i Think this is not the syntax error,  i am not able to identify the problem in the code as per my expectation it should work correctly. Please suggest me what is the problem in the function print_list or is there any problem in the call of the same function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    }mynode;
void add(mynode **, int);
void print_list(mynode *);
main()
{
mynode *head=NULL;

add(&head, 10);
add(&head, 100);
add(&head, 1000);
print_list(head);
}

void add(mynode **head_1, int value)
{
 mynode *temp=NULL;
 mynode ** head = head_1;
 temp = malloc(sizeof(mynode));
 temp->value = value;
 temp->next = NULL;
 if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(*head!=NULL)
        {
            *head = (*head)->next;
        }
        *head = temp;
    }
    return;
}
void print_list(mynode *head)
(
    mynode *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    printf("%d \t", temp->value);    
    }

    )
```

Comment: In C blocks and function bodies starts with '{'

Answer (score 8):

Use `{` instead of `(`.

```
void print_list(mynode *head)
{
    mynode *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    printf("%d \t", temp->value);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used wrong braces

```
 void print_list(mynode *head)
( //error should be {
    mynode *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    printf("%d \t", temp->value);    
    }

    )//error should be }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `{` for a function body instead of '('